# iOS Swift Get CGPoint on tap of UITableView with following cell content

Tags: ios, swift

So cell contains attributed text, with all content(sentence) tappable.(This part is working fine.)

And now need to get CGPoint on screen where user taps on any of content to show a popup menu to give multiple options.

Code that I tried, but it's not gets called as i have attributed text which is clickable. If i remove clickable attributed text then this function gets called.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { 
    let point = touches.first?.location(in: self.view) 
}
```

Comment: can u share what code u tried?

Comment: override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let point = touches.first?.location(in: self.view)
}

Comment: @abh do you have any suggestion now?

Comment: Ok, and what does that code do when you try it? What do you do with the point you receive? The code you posted just puts the point into a local variable... and then does nothing.

Comment: Check in question need that point to show popup menu, but this function does not get called, as cell has attributed clickable text. If i removed attributed text then function gets called.